# Determinant of an identity matrix multiplied by a unit complex number

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I have read on solution to homework question that for $I\epsilon M_n(\mathbb{C})$,
$$ \det(e^{-i\theta/n}I) = e^{-i\theta} $$
But I do not understand, why is the complex number not treated like a constant and taken out front, somehow it is multiplied by n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant function is multi-linear which means it's linear in each row rather than for the whole matrix. In general for an $n \times n$ matrix A then $\det (kA)=k^n \det(A)$ because we have to factor out the $k$ from each row separately.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the diagonal entries. So, $\det(cI) = c^n$. Your misconception is that you seem to be thinking of $\det$ as a linear function, when it is actually a multi-linear function of the columns (or rows) of a matrix.

In particular, if $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are vectors, and $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with $v_i$ as the $i^{th}$ column, then for any constants $c_1, \dots, c_n$,
\begin{align}
\det(c_1v_1, \dots, c_n v_n) = c_1\cdots c_n \det (v_1, \dots, v_n)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Or rather, it's raised to the $n$th power.  Take the determinant of the following:

$$
\det \left [ \begin{array}{cccc}
e^{-i\theta/n} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & e^{-i\theta/n} & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & e^{-i\theta/n}\\
\end{array} \right ].
$$